# Can you cast variables to functions in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, casting

I saw this code in the buffer overflow SEED lab.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

const char shellcode[] =
#if __x86_64__
    "\x48\x31\xd2\x52\x48\xb8\x2f\x62\x69\x6e"
    "\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x50\x48\x89\xe7\x52\x57"
    "\x48\x89\xe6\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x3b\x0f\x05"
#else
    "\x31\xc0\x50\x68\x2f\x2f\x73\x68\x68\x2f"
    "\x62\x69\x6e\x89\xe3\x50\x53\x89\xe1\x31"
    "\xd2\x31\xc0\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80"
#endif
;


int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
    char code[500];
    strcpy(code, shellcode); // Copy the shellcode to the stack
    int (*func)() = (int(*)())code;
    func();                 // Invoke the shellcode from the stack
    return 1;
}
```

can someone explain to me whats happening in the main function, are they casting a variable to a function, and if so how does that work?

Comment: That's Undefined Behavior. As far as the language is concerned, this code is broken.

Comment: Basically, it is undefined behaviour, but your implementation might compile it OK.

Comment: Still, it's clever.  Not sure why you wouldn't just use a proper assembler, though, or inline assembly.

Comment: Maybe he is a cracker and wants to inject code.

Answer (score 0):

> can someone explain to me whats happening in the main function, are
> they casting a variable to a function, and if so how does that work?

1. It is not a function, only function **pointer**

Generally, it is undefined behaviour, but your implementation may represent pointers to data and function pointers in the same way.

If yes ten address of the first of the element of the `shellcode` array is assigned to the function pointer. Next, you execute the code referenced by this function pointer.